# How to give a program administrator privilige in linux?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I am very new in such things so point me if I'm wrong.
I want to execute some terminal commands(to turn of GPU) on my computer on every time my computer starts. Those commands require super user privileges so when I execute them manually I write sudo su then password. But I want to execute those commands with python code. How should I do this.
I tried this code but it failed

```
import os
os.system('sudo su')
print my_computer_password
#then four lines of command which turn off GPU
```

these lines of code doesn't work because print statement doesn't fill password dialogue...

Comment: In the case we have for this, we added the user to the `/etc/sudoers` file with `NOPASSWD` option.  Maybe not the most secure, but it works and is secure enough in our case.

Comment: the best would be to just run it at boot, e.g. as init.d task (just remember to make script read-only).

Comment: @cmd, if someone can log in as you to take advantage of the NOPASSWD, they can inspect the script for the password anyway

Comment: @gnibbler thats true, storing the passwd in a user script is even less secure then the NOPASSWD option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the subprocess module so you can communicate with it.

```
import subprocess as sp
prog = sp.Popen(['sudo','whateverprogram'],stdin=sp.PIPE)
prog.stdin.write('password')
prog.communicate()
```

Comment: it doesn't work
I tries this
`import subprocess as sp;
prog = sp.Popen(['sudo','nautilus /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch'],stdin=sp.PIPE);
prog.stdin.write('mypass');
prog.communicate()`
it says command not found... what is wrong

Comment: try a ['sudo','/path/to/nautilus','/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch']